# How do I get number of a XML nodes child in c# XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML file structure:

```
<classes>
  <Base Name="node1">
        <Book Name="child01" CoverArtName="C102.jpg" CoverBaseFolder="" Tooltip=""  PluginBook=""/> 
        <Book Name="child02" CoverArtName="C102.jpg" CoverBaseFolder="" Tooltip=""  PluginBook=""/> 
        <Book Name="child03" CoverArtName="C102.jpg" CoverBaseFolder="" Tooltip=""  PluginBook=""/> 
  </Base >
  <Base Name="node2">
        <Book Name="child01" CoverArtName="C102.jpg" CoverBaseFolder="" Tooltip=""  PluginBook=""/> 
        <Book Name="child02" CoverArtName="C102.jpg" CoverBaseFolder="" Tooltip=""  PluginBook=""/> 
  </Base >
  <Base Name="node3">
  </Base >
</classes>
```

How can I get the number of child nodes for each node using *XmlReader*?

**Update:**
I read my XML with thes code:

```
List<Bases> base7 = new List<Bases>();

XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("Books.xml");
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "Base"))
            {
                if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
                    Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.GetAttribute("Name") + ": " + xmlReader.GetAttribute("CoverBaseFolder"));
            //Base Name
                base7.Add(new Bases() { BaseName = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Name"), Basefolder = xmlReader.GetAttribute("CoverBaseFolder") });
            }
        }
        mainbox.ItemsSource = base7;
```

The output is a list item with name of node and number of child elements of same node.

Comment: do you have code that can read it?

Comment: Could you provide an expected output for your example?

Comment: My code for reading the XML has been added.

Comment: yes, I want a list item that show name of the "node" and number of children

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done easily by using LinqToXml:

```
var list = XElement.Load("test.xml")
    .Elements("Base")
    .Select(e => new
    {
        Name = e.Attribute("Name").Value,
        Count = e.Elements().Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

But if you want to use the `XmlReader`, for example, to work with xml that does not fit in memory, the code is much more cumbersome:

```
var bases = new List<Base>();

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "Base"))
        {
            var name = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Name");
            int count = 0;
            using (var innerReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                while (innerReader.Read())
                {
                    if (innerReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && innerReader.Name == "Book")
                        count++;
                }
            }
            bases.Add(new Base { Name = name, Count = count });
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

To count the child nodes is convenient to use the [ReadSubtree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The `XmlReader` class has many useful methods. Use `ReadToFollowing` method allows to slightly reduce code.

```
var bases = new List<Base>();

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Base"))
    {
        string name = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Name");
        int count = 0;
        using (var innerReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            while (innerReader.ReadToFollowing("Book"))
                count++;
        }
        bases.Add(new Base { Name = name, Count = count });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander :) it is very neat and useful!